# Django Translations for displaying translated messages on the same template fails to translate

Tags: python, django, translation

My django applicaton and translations runs perfectly except a single situation.

I have an error and a success view and template that renders different messages into the same two templates (one for success messages and the other for fails and errors)

My general error view is as follows:

```
@login_required
@never_cache
def base_error_page(request, error="", title=""):
    context = {'error': error, 'title': title + " | "}
    return render_to_response('general_pages/operation_failed.html', context,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request, {}))
```

And my error template at `general_pages/operation_failed.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    {% autoescape off %}
    <h2>{{ title|slice:":-3" }}</h2>
    <table class="info_table">
        <tr>
            <th><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/failure.png"></th>
            <td style="font-weight: bold">{{ error }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I simply give the translated string to my page view, and it displays the message on the page. Usege is as follows

Some view.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
def someview(request):
    ...
    ...
    if some_error:
        return base_error_page(request, error=_('Update Failed <br />'
                                                '<a href="%(profile)s">Back to Profile Settings »»</a>') % {"profile": reverse('custom_profile')}, 
                                        title=_("Update Profile"))
```

But my fail (and success) page messages do not translated into the selected language. All other translations works fine.

I am using `Djnago 1.6.5`

Comment: Do you use i18n urls?

Comment: Also since you are appending a dynamic value probably your string does not match the translated one, you should actually use the error message only and create the profile link inside the template using a flag (something like checking if the error is assigned).

Comment: Yes, and all other views and templates works just fine. I use string translations as described in the [template section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation)

Comment: Yes but is that url always the same? if the url changes then your translated string will not match then one in the po file.
Use:
`error=_('Update Failed')` and create the rest of the string inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it this way:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def someview(request):
    ...
    ...
    if some_error:
        return render_to_response('general_pages/operation_failed.html', {"error":_("update failed")},
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then let the template do the rest:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    {% autoescape off %}
    <h2>{{ title|slice:":-3" }}</h2>
    <table class="info_table">
        <tr>
            <th><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}img/failure.png"></th>
            <td style="font-weight: bold">{{ error|title }}<br /><a href="{% url "custom_profile" %}">{% trans "back to profile settings"|title %} »»</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    {% endautoescape %}
{% endblock content %}
```